# Redirect problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this code in the client side:

```
$.post('<%=Url.Action("Action_Name","Controller_Name")%>', { serverParam: clientParam}, null, null);
```

And this code in the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action_Name(string serverParam)
{
    return View();
}
```

I currently am in a view and when i click a button i want to be redirected to `Controller_Name`/`Action_Name`/`serverParam`.
After the post i am sent in the action method but i still see the old view, not `Action_Name`
(`Action_Name.aspx` exists)
(I am using mvc 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should follow the "Post/Redirect/Get" pattern by returning a redirect result instead of a view after a successful post. But that would not solve the problem you're actually asking about.

This is doing an AJAX `POST`, not a "regular" `POST`. So the browser isn't going to honor a redirect response by redirecting. You could "redirect" in your response callback by setting `window.location`, but...

The easiest way to do what you want is to just post the form, rather than using `$.post`, which is a shortcut to `$.ajax`, like this:

```
$("#someForm").submit();
```